# Foreign Key no Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bom dia, estou a alguns dias com um problema utilizando o Rails5, não consigo inserir foreign key.

Models:

```
class Sushi < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :tipo_sushi
end

class TipoSushi < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sushi
end
```

---

Migration:

```
class CreateSushis < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :sushis do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :value
      t.integer :tipo_sushi_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sushis, :tipo_sushi_id
  end
end

class CreateTipoSushis < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tipo_sushis do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

---

View principal:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :value %>
    <%= f.text_field :value %>
  </div>

  <div>
  <%= f.label :Tipo_Sushi%>
  <%= f.select(:tipo_sushi_id, TipoSushi.all.collect { |c| [ c.name, c.id ] }) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Explicando, eu cadastro um tipo de sushi, depois quando vou cadastrar o Sushi, defino o nome, valor e o tipo, no tipo aparece uma lista dos tipos cadastrados anteriormente, até aí tá funcionando, preciso no formulário submeter o ID do tipo sushi, porem dá erro, conforme abaixo.

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by SushisController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U82zJsuqvkVLeiRw97Ma01yzSHJ4EuDBJLJYsZvOT0tv2c030cNN0xhaWuxMudjopJmtASnnTrTMZiRiC0ZCzg==", "sushi"=>{"name"=>"Tipo1", "value"=>"30", "tipo_sushi_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Sushi"}
Unpermitted parameter: tipo_sushi_id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: A versão 5 do rails não tá em beta?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi no site dia 30 de junho deixou de ser(se etendi correto)

Answer (score 0):

Tente modificar o seu controller para ficar desta forma.

```
def create
    @sushi = Sushi.new(sushi_params)
    if @sushi.save
        # Sucesso.
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

    def sushi_params
        params.require(:sushi).permit(:name, :value, :tipo_sushi_id)
    end
```

É um replace para o attr_accessible do antigo rails que não é utilizado mais desde a versão 4, chamado de **Strong Params**.